# Storing application configuration data into a static list

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, static

I am implementing MVVM in a WPF application and I have a hard time deciding where and how to store my configuration data (loaded from an xml file) so it's accessible in every View Model. So what I came up with is:

```
static class Configurations
{
    private static List<object> Container = new List<object>();

    public static void LoadConfigurations() { }
    public static List<object> GetConfiguration(string configuration)
    {
        -- return the needed subelement --
        return Container(configuration);
    }

}
```

I am thinking of using a static class because this would be accessible without passing any data between the view models.
I would just have to call **Configurations.LoadConfigurations()** at the start of the application and call **Configurations.GetConfigurations()** when It's needed.

So my question is, is it a good way to deal with this kind of situations or it's bad practice?

Don't mind the correctness of the code, it's only for example purpose.

Comment: IMHO Loading a configuration and keeping it in static is good practice. I have used App.xaml.cs to keep the static information like UserRole, Current User . So i haven't experience any issue on the same.

Comment: I agree with Eldho, thats what everybody does.

Comment: Look at Application.Current.Properties

Comment: This question is too broad and all the answers will be probably opinion-based. The "neutral" answer would be: **it depends**. E.g. if you're using something like Prism, you certainly would prefer an instance of such a settings class that you can inject in your view models via the DI container.

Answer (score 1):

> So my question is, is it a good way to deal with this kind of situations or it's bad practice?

It depends :) But if you want to be able to unit test your view models you also want to be able to mock the configuration settings. In this case you would be better off using a shared service that you inject your view model classes with.

The service should implement an interface:

```
public interface IConfiguration
{
    List<object> GetConfiguration(string configuration);
}

public class Configurations : IConfiguration
{
    private readonly List<object> Container = new List<object>();

    public List<object> GetConfiguration(string configuration)
    {
        -- return the needed subelement --
        return Container(configuration);
    }
}
```

You can then simply provide another implementation of this interface in your unit test:

```
IConfiguration config = new Configurations(); //or any other implementation...
ViewModel vm = new ViewModel(config);
```

**View Model:**

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public ViewModel(IConfiguration config)
    {
        var config = config.GetConfiguration("...");
        //...
    }
}
```